# Can Entrust RBAC system store permissions in CODE rather than in DB?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, rbac

Im considering https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust#permission library to add RBAC functions to Laravel.

But as it seems Permissions are stored as Eloquent models in Database. I don't see the point in storing it in Database since only developers can add\modify permissions while developing code. There is a strong point in assigning permissions to roles that Entrust does well.

Can I use "Entrust" while storing it's permissions in PHP-array rather than in DB?

Or maybe more general - can I use array as storage for Eloquent models?